# How to cache online tiles on a development machine?

Tags: openlayers-2, tilecache, cache

I am developing a slippy map web application using openlayers. Right now my tiles come straight away from OSM and google, etc. For the moment I always work on the same area for development purposes and I would like to have those tiles cached on my dev machine so I can work on the web app offline yet still see some map and to reduce network consumption.

What I would like is to set up some sort of proxy which would just cache tiles I watch and if they are not on the local machine download them or show a dummy tile if I am offline.

I thought tilecache was the tool for this, but I get quite confused trying to set it up. It seems more appropriate for mapserver generating tiles from map data. I know firefox does some caching, but I would like some more control and be able to clear that cache to make sure I see the last update of my work.

What is the most straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ProxySimplePHP and use your computer as the host - if it needs more tiles it grabs them from the a.tile.openstreetmap.org, b.tile.openstreetmap.org servers on demand

Comment: Thank you, that looks very nice... Probably it's easily adapted for othe servers as well

Answer (score 3):

With your purpose, i think mapproxy (www.mapproxy.org) is the best choice. MapProxy not only caches tiles, wms source but also serve the cached tiles as TMS, WMS.

Comment: Or for that matter, any tile cache service, such as http://tilecache.org/, http://geowebcache.org/.. etc

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to generate your own tiles on the disk: http://braincrunch.tumblr.com/post/9921938947/maperitive-tutorial-a-hiking-web-map-in-ten-easy-steps (you only need steps 1, 3, 5 and 7).